# Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am completely newbie for Android studio and Android development. Any help would grateful. I am using Android Studio version 2.3.3.

After I created a project I am getting below error.[image]

Comment: Post the contents of app/build.gradle

Comment: seems like you need to download these jars , you don't have it , there must a message to enable the internet and synch these files , click on it , make sure you have the internet

Comment: connect to the internet!

Comment: I am connected to the internet. I am using office internet and computer, will there be any proxy settings needed in Android studio? I checked the "Auto-detect proxy settings" option under HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 1):

Your latest installation of android studio `2.3+` doesn't have the dependencies , so you need to download it

1.) Connect to internet

2.) Run gradle synch or run your program

3.) Let the gradle download these dependencies

Note : it will be a one time process and will not be required for other projects

Comment: Could you please share the link to download? I already installed 2.3.3 and there wont be any issue if i install 3.0+?

Comment: nope, you have to download these dependencies , in your error logs, there should be a link to synch your project , make sure your system has an internet connection

Comment: here is the link https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html to download latest studio version but it will again ask to download these dependencies and these won't take much time , small in size

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Pavneet. Uninstalled the older version and downloading the 3.0 version. Hope i  won't face any issues :)

Comment: nope , the issues will be there so please make sure to click the synch link to download these dependencies first time you create any project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. I just used VPN and then let the gradle download dependencies(by clicking on sync button in build.gradle).For me it wasn't needed to change any proxy settings in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your quick response!!

To my surprise this has started working connecting from personal internet. Still wondering why it was not working with office network!!

Comment: It could be your computer / companies firewall or proxy blocking Gradle to sync. 
Your browser pages might work flawlessly, downloading AS might go with no problems, but still Gradle can has its own problems connecting.

The quickest solution, since I am on this for to long already, is connecting to my phone internet to sync gradle and after that you can just do your work. After you have synced your libraries you could go in offline mode if needed.
It is not a final solution, but in my case I just need it for a few weeks. :)